# Conditional statistics: a function of two random variables that are individually independent to another random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Say I have three random variables $x,y,$ and $z$. Suppose that $x$ is independent of $z$. Also, suppose that $y$ is independent of $z$. Then, is an arbitrary function of $x$ and $y$ independent of $z$?

In other words, is $f(g(x,y)|z)=f(g(x,y))$ where $f$ denotes the probabilty density function and $g$ is an arbitrary function?

Intuitively, I think it should be but I have yet to be able to prove so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

As a discrete counterexample, consider throwing an $8$-sided die, so $D$ can take the values $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ with equal probability.

- Let $X$ be $1$ if $D \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $0$ otherwise
- Let $Y$ be $1$ if $D \in \{1,3,6,8\}$ and $0$ otherwise
- Let $Z$ be $1$ if $D \in \{2,4,6,8\}$ and $0$ otherwise

Then $X$ is independent of $Z$ and $Y$ is independent of $Z$, but $G(X,Y)=XY$ is not independent of $Z$

There are also counterexamples for continuous random variables